# Can Xcode device simulators be used as a reliable way of testing app compatibility with older iOS versions?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I was testing my app with the Xcode device simulators to make sure all features work well with at least iOS 8.1 and I realized something that has me confused. There was a bit of code with functionality that has availability as of 8.3, but when I ran my app on the simulator running 8.1 everything worked as expected. What's going on with this? Is it even worth supporting below 9.0 given that almost 90% of users have 9.0+?

Comment: It's probably not worth supporting below iOS 9 at this point but it depends on your user base. Also, Apple sometimes tests API in iOS privately prior to making it public. Do not use an API in any version of iOS prior to its public release as the behaviour is not guaranteed to be the same (or even to work consistently and it's usually not bug-free).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code in question related to a class that was released with a previous OS version? If the object itself wasn't available when the OS version you have set as your Deployment Target was released, you should get a compile time error that says "XX is only available on iOS X.X or newer"

If it's only a new method to an existing class, you can probably get it to build and simulate. Invoking the code should crash your app though. Use a log statement to make sure the method is actually being called.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, most of the time you should use simulators to test UI and your data calculations or application/business logic are working or not. But you have to try on real device to test the performance of your applications as every iPhone's hardware is different. Back to your original question - When you say everything works fine on Simulator but not on real device, is there any specific thing you are trying to debug?

Comment: Well it works fine on both the simulator and the device. What I don't understand is if the code became available as of iOS 8.3, how does it run on the simulator running iOS 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

you should use device for testing purposes because there is huge difference between implementing things in simulators and in real device. You can use simulators for logic testing purposes.